# How to get the image form the H264 raw data

Tags: c++, imagedecoder

I am acquiring the data from AXIS camera by using RTSP API.
I want to extract the image from the received raw data (h264 codec format)

I am using libturbojpeg to compress the data and cximage to create an image

```
  int result = tjCompress2(m_tjCompressorHandle,reinterpret_cast<const 
  unsigned char *> (pcImgContent),SCALE(320, 1),0, SCALE(240, 1), 
  TJPF_RGB, &pData, &resultSize, TJSAMP_444, 100, TJFLAG_ACCURATEDCT);
```

1. Can i use libturbojpeg directly for h264 raw data?
2. Do i need to use some other library before compression?

Comment: Are you receiving h264 data or compressing image that you create using cximage?

Comment: I am receiving h264 data

Comment: then why are you trying to compress it?

Comment: Can i see that data without compression or any processing?

Comment: h264 is already compressed so you'll need to decompress it.

Comment: Any library or way to decompress it in c++?

Comment: I have decoded the images Thank you.